# what if unmanaged resources are not disposed?

Tags: vb.net, memory

in my application , there are a lot of oledbConnections and data Tables and data sources and more unmanaged resources .. some of them be disposed (by calling Dispose() when them are not longer needed) and the another do not have Dispose() (just for make code lines more less !) .
the question is : Is there any problem will be on applictaion if those unmanaged resources are not disposed after use them ?

i have sometimes (not all time) an error "appname was stopped working .." , is this error caused by the un Disposed objects ?

finally , what are the cases that when calling Dispose() , an error occured ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends to some extent on what the unmanaged resource is.  If it's a database connection, you'll eventually run out of connections.  That is, all of the connections in the connection pool will be open but unused.  The database server at that point won't allow any new connections.  So you'll no longer be able to connect to the database.

Similar problems occur with other types of resources.  You'll be leaking them and you can get yourself into all sorts of strange, hard to debug situations.

Best practice is to always call `Dispose` or `Close` if the class has that method when you're done with it.  In C#, you can use a `using` statement for just this reason.  I don't know what the VB.net equivalent syntax is, but whatever it is, you should use it.

Comment: VB.NET also has [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) clause.

Answer (score 0):

It is always the best practice to Dispose of everything once you are done using them. When you use dispose you clean up the managed and unmanaged resources. Not properly disposing of these can cause problems and memory leaks which could be the reason why you are getting that error message. Just add the Dispose() method :) A few extra lines of code can save you in the end.

Comment: thank you very much , yes :( a "memory leak" error was occured before somedays